# Interchange of Lebesgue integrals and infinite sums

Tags: summation, lebesgue-integral

I am self-learning the Analysis II book from Tao [[1](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/analysis-ii/)], and stopped with the following problem (8.2.4):
For each $n=1,2,3...$ let $ f_n : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $ f_n(x) = \chi(x)_{[n,n+1)} - \chi(x)_{[n+1, n+2)}$, where $\chi()$ denotes the indicator function, i.e., $f_n(x) = 1, \forall x \in [n,n+1)$, $f_n(x) = -1, \forall x \in [n+1,n+2)$, and zero otherwise. Show that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x) \neq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)$$

My attempts:

(1) since $f_n(x)$ is not non-negative, then the integrals and sums cannot be exchanged. Period (?)

(2) Defining $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) = sup \{\int_{\mathbb{R}}s\}$ for $s$ being a simple function that minorizes $f(x)$. Since $f(x) \in \{-1,0,1\} \forall x$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}s = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nm([n,n+1)-b_nm([n+1,n+2))$, where $m()$ is the Lebesgue measure. Sice $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x) = 0$, at the limit point the measure is zero. This results in $\int_{\mathbb{R}}s = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$, and so, the integral is not convergent. On the other side, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x) = 0$, for all $n=1,2..$, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)=0$.

Do these attempts make any sense? Did I make some mistakes here? Thanks for all the possible hints/explanations.

Answer (score 1):

- Your statement (1) is wrong and not needed. There are plenty of sequences of non-negative and non-positive functions $f_n$ for which we can interchange limits and sums with integrals. Hint: *Dominated Convergence Theorem.*
- The first sentence in paragraph (2) is doubtful: $\int_\mathbb Rf$ is the supremum of $\int_\mathbb R s$ where $s\le f,\, s$ simple, holds for
  *non-negative* $f$. At this stage we don't know yet if our $f$ is non-negative.
- You have correctly observed that, for all $n$,
  $$
  \int_{\mathbb R}f_n(x)\,dx=0
  $$
  holds, so that
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R}f_n(x)\,dx=0\,.
  $$
- On the other hand
  \begin{align}
  f_1&=\chi_{[1,2)}-\chi_{[2,3)}\\
  f_2&=\chi_{[2,3)}-\chi_{[3,4)}\\
  &...
  \end{align}
  Therefore,
  $$
  f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n=\chi_{[1,2)}\,
  $$
  which has integral one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Indeed, opening the sum it turns to be a telescopic sum that cancels all terms except the first one.